# With cakePHP, can I increment the value of a column without reading it's value first?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'd like to increment the value of a column in cakePHP. 
Is there a way to have cakePHP write this?

```
UPDATE `gigs` SET `visits` = visits+1 WHERE `gigs`.`id` = 1
```

I tried this:

```
function addVisit($id){
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->saveField('visits', 'visits+1');
}
```

but cakePHP adds quotes around visits+1.

```
UPDATE `gigs` SET `visits` = 'visits+1' WHERE `gigs`.`id` = 1
```

I tried double quotes, results the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$this->updateAll(array(), array('Model.field + 1'))
```

or

```
$this->updateAll(null, array('Model.field + 1'))
```

one of them should work, saveField does not allow sql fragments, updateAll does

Comment: The correct answer is $this->updateAll(array('Model.field' =>'Model.field + 1'), array('Model.id' => $id));